# Shows install success in ADB .but not running on device

Tags: android

I created hello world application (in android 2.1). It successfully installed , signed. I installed it on my device (sony xperia x10 mini android version 2.1) using ADB. I used install command in ADB ,there it has shown me success message.

But, after that I disconnected disconnected my device . After browsing in appInstaller , I got to see my application. After that I installed it  there . There is has shown me install success message . But application open option is deactivated. Hence I am not able to run the application.

So could be the reason. If need more details about steps I followed please let me know.

Comment: Does it work in the emulator?

Comment: do you see your App at all in Launcher?

Comment: @ CommonsWare : In my emulator am not getting application browser to run my application.  After running the application in eclipse the running application window is expected in emulator ,which is not happening.  But in my case after running application virtual device is opening with main background screen ,and no hello world screen. And in eclipse it is showing me the success message.